# Is there $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ injective such that...

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, morse-theory

Let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $C^{1}$ injective where $U$ is a open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  (so $f$ is open by invariance domain theorem).

a) Is there exist $f$ such that  dim $ker(df_{x}) >$ dim $im(df_{x})$ for all $x \in U$ ?

b) Is there exist $f$ such that  dim $ker(df_{x}) <$ dim $im(df_{x})$  for all $x \in U$ ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean dimension of $ker$ and $im$ ?

Comment: yes, I'll change, thank you

Comment: a) is false by sard's theorem.